# Export class from typescript namespace give undefined after compiling (NestJS)

Tags: node.js, typescript, class, namespaces, nestjs

The problem is so simple, i want to use namespaces in order to regroupe some classes but whenever i try to import a class from this namespace it return

> cannot read property of undefined namespace error.

Here is an example

Namespace file example :

```
import { Entity, Column, BaseEntity, Connection, QueryRunner, MigrationInterface, Table } from "typeorm";
import { DB_CONNECTION_PROVIDER } from "./database.providers";
import { EntityDefinition } from "./entity.definition";

/**
 * Each namespace has to have Entity and Migration functions
 * @definition define the user repository, service, table and schema name the table schema
 * @entity define the table schema
 * @TableMigration define the table migration(up, down)
*/ 
export namespace User{

    export enum ROLE {
        SUPERADMIN = "SUPERADMIN",
        CLIENT = "CLIENT",
    }
    export class Definition implements EntityDefinition {
        static readonly tableName = "users";
        static readonly schemaName = "user";
        static readonly REPOSITORY_NAME = "USERS_REPOSITORY";
        static service = {
            provide: Definition.REPOSITORY_NAME,
            useFactory: (connection: Connection) => connection.getRepository(UEntity),
            inject: [DB_CONNECTION_PROVIDER],
        };
    }
    export class UTable implements MigrationInterface {
        constructor() {

        }
        public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
            await queryRunner.createTable(new Table(UEntity), false,);
        }
        public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
            // queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE article`);
        }
    }



    @Entity({ name: User.Definition.tableName, schema: User.Definition.schemaName })
    export class UEntity extends BaseEntity {
        @Column({ type: "string", nullable: false })
        firstname: string;

        @Column({ type: "string", nullable: false })
        lastname: string;

        @Column({ type: "enum", enum: User.ROLE, nullable: false })
        role: User.ROLE;

        @Column({ type: "string", unique: true, nullable: false })
        email: string;

        @Column({ type: "string", nullable: false })
        password: string;

        @Column({ type: "string", nullable: false })
        picture: string;

        @Column({ type: "date", nullable: false })
        birthday: Date;

        @Column({ type: "string", nullable: false })
        country: string;

        @Column({ type: "string", nullable: false })
        city: string;

        @Column({ type: "string", nullable: false })
        phone: string;

        @Column({ type: "boolean", default: false })
        isdelete: boolean;

        @Column({ type: "string", nullable: true })
        oauth_provider_id?: string;

        @Column({ type: "string", nullable: true })
        oauth_provider_token?: string;

        @Column({ type: "timestamp" })
        createdAt: Date;

        @Column({ type: "timestamp" })
        updatedAt: Date;
    }
}
```

And here is how i import and use the namespace class

```
import { User } from './user.entity';
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';
import { PostgresConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresConnectionOptions';

const host = process.env.DB_HOST;
const port = parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT);
const username = process.env.DB_USERNAME;
const password = process.env.DB_PASSWORD;
const dbName = process.env.DB_NAME;

const migrations = [
    User.UTable
]
const entities = [
    User.UEntity
]

export const DB_CONNECTION_PROVIDER = "DATABASE_CONNECTION";

export const dbConfig: PostgresConnectionOptions = {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: host,
    port: port,
    username: username,
    password: password,
    database: dbName,
    synchronize: false, // don't allow entity to update database alone
    entities: [...entities],
    migrations:[...migrations],
    uuidExtension: "uuid-ossp",
}
export const databaseProvider = {
    provide: DB_CONNECTION_PROVIDER,
    useFactory: async () => await createConnection(dbConfig)
}
```

And here is what i get as an error

> user_entity_1.User.UTable
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'UTable' of undefined
> at Object. (/Volumes/Secondary/Transport/transport-app/dist/models/database.providers.js:12:24)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
> at Object. (/Volumes/Secondary/Transport/transport-app/dist/models/user.entity.js:14:30)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)

I don't know if the problem with typescript or namespaces use case.

I hope you can explain to me what is happening

Comment: I can't event get something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIgU1DAvDAFANwIYBsBcM0ATgJZgDmAlIQMK7YQSKjHZQjGoB8MA3gFgAUDFExiCKAFdiYDFGzEKkqj37CxmmKEghcCAHS4QFLHioBuDVtETpsmAqWSrIsQF9hnocLDYAtggQAA7YwAgwAGIgIOo+bqLADEzwCABmcTai0OykwNpS0CD+AHIBEWgA5NEgldai3vUwAAIsIOg1BohpBsCFHKXlVE1JjBAwAEKKmVk5UHnayRBlgagwlQBGipWumt7uQA) to compile. How are you able to access the `Namesapce.Class`?

Comment: you need to add export to the Def class but for it's compiler problem , even when i debug it give me name of js classes

Comment: Like this for you @JayMcDoniel [https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIgU1DAvDAFANwIYBsBcM0ATgJZgDmAlIQMK7YQSKjHZQjGoB8MA3gFgAUDFExiCKAFdiYDFGzEKkqj37CxmmKEghcCAHS4QFLHioBuDVtETpsmAqWSrIsQF9hnocLDYAtggQAA7YwAgwAGIgIOo+bqIIAB7BnLDADEzwCABmcTai0OykwNpS0CD+AHIBEWgA5NEg9dai3q0wAAIsIOhNBog5BsDlHNW1VB0ZjBAwAEKK+QVFUCXamRA1gagw9QBGivWumt7uQA] (example)

Comment: Would you mind adding the file names to your code blocks? It looks like it might be a circular reference somewhere

Comment: user.entity.ts and the second is database.provider.ts

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you have a circular reference between the two files. Your `user.entity.ts` imports `database.provider.ts` to get the `DB_CONNECTION_PROVIDER` token, and the `database.provider.ts` imports `user.entity.ts` to get the `User` namespace. What I would do here is move the `DB_CONNECTION_PROVIDER` token to a separate `database.constants.ts` file, and import it from there in both files so you remove the circular dependency between the files